# How does it work using ASP.NET FormAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, webforms, owin, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

Our ASP.NET website is using `FormAuthentication`. After login success, it will add a cookie to client side. Here is the code.

```
 FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
 username,
 DateTime.Now,
 expiration,
 remember,
 roles,
 FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);

 HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));

 Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Then I can see that a cookie with name `.ASPXAUTH` is created in client browser. Next time, when I visit the website, I can see that `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` is marked into `true` automatically. I guess ASP.NET decrypt the cookie and get the user information.

How can I debug this process? I want to see the source code to find out how `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` is assgined into true.

Comment: it's all on https://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: Acutally, I don't know how to begin. Do you know in which class it starts to read cookie and authenticate request?

Comment: It's not _that_ simple: exactly what happens is determined by your `web.config` file (including defaults inherited from `machine.config` and `applicationHost.config`). You need to work your way through it yourself; there are no short, easy, answers here.